# Importing project files in python

Tags: python

I mostly worked on PHP where it was really easy to import classes specially after composer. But I am having hard times applying same directory structure in Python project.

I have the following directory structure.

`backend
   commands
       indices.py
       backup.py
       etc.py
   components
       mapping
           product.py
       storage
           Es.py
   interfaces
        StorageInterface.py
        IndexInterface.py`

My commands folder is basically the files i will run through cli where as the components will hold the actual business logic and interfaces just contains the ABCs for components.

I have to do several imports throughout the code some times from same folder sometimes from subfolder and sometimes same level another folder.

For example in my indices.py file i have this import

```
from components.storage.Es import Es
```

This gives me

```
root@07fc62bd3c97:/backend/commands# python indices.py --help 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "indices.py", line 1, in <module> from components.storage.Es import Es ImportError: No module named components.storage.Es
```

I have gone through other answers on SO and found really dirty solutions of putting sys and os modules and adding files in runtime. This could be okay when its 1 2 files but managing the whole project looks really bad.

My questions here are

1 - Am i following the pythonic way of managing a project
2 - How can i access all my classes files in a neat way

Thanks

Comment: For the negative marker. I don't care as long as i am able to learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat your entire `backend` folder like a package. If you're using legacy Python (Python 2), you'll need to put `__init__.py` files in all the folders so they are importable as subpackages. You'd need to either tweak your imports to then be `from backend.components.storage.Es`, or `from ..components.storage.Es` (relative imports).

Then, because it's all a package, you'll find that you can't go into a subfolder and execute code. The fix then is to run the code (e.g. `backend/commands/backup.py`) by using the `-m` module flag: `python -m backend.commands.backup` from the folder containing `backend`. If you want, you can add an entrypoint later by making a `setup.py` that would turn it into a prettier command.

Comment: I created a ```src``` folder inside ```backend``` folder and added ```__init__.py``` in all my modules. Now i can run my commands from backend folder like ```python -m src.commands.indices```. So far so good. Just wanted to be sure that is this the industry standard of handling python cli projects ?

Answer (score 2):

You need `__init__.py` files in the `commands`, `components`, `mapping`, `storage`, and `interfaces` subdirectories in order for those directories and the files contained within them to be considered modules by python.  Also, having individual modules which have the same name as some class which is defined inside of them is not really pythonic.  For example, it's better to have an `interfaces` module defined by an `interfaces.py` file which contains both interface classes than to have two files named `StorageInterface.py` and `IndexInterface.py` which each contain a class definiton (I'm assuming that's what you're doing there).

Also, it matters what directory you start the python process from.  In order for that import path to be meaningful, I'm pretty sure you'd need to start the python process from within the `backend` directory.  Or you'd need to add the filesystem paths of the `components`, `commands`, etc. subdirectories to python's module path via the `PYTHONPATH` env var or by some other method.